# OOP PHP with Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

If we have a code like this:

```
class Game {
    private $_id;
    private $_name;
    private $_url;

    public function __construct($_id,$_name,$_url){
        $this->_id = $_id;
        $this->_name = $_name;
        $this->_url = $_url;
    }
}
```

And we want to simply connect to our Database to get a game by id, where do we place the 'getByID' function?

Do we place it within the 'Game Class' as 'static function', do we put it in the 'Database Connection Class' as 'public function' or do we just put the method in the 'general functions inside the main index.php' as 'function'?

I currenctly have choosen for a 'static function' within the 'Game Class':

```
public static function getByID($id,$db){    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM game WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
    $prepare = array(":id"=>$id);
    $result = $db->Precute($query,$prepare);
    foreach($result as $r) return new Game($r['id'],$r['name'],$r['url']);
    return null;
}
```

(Precute is a custom function within the Database Class to prepare and execute the query)
How would you approach this?

Comment: Remove the quote in `$this->_url = $_url';` for one thing. That will surely throw an error, unless that's a typo.

Comment: I think a static method is fine . P.S - did you consider using a php framework ? It's exactly these kind of code organization problems that a framework will solve for you...

Comment: Thank you Fred -ii-, I've corrected the typo.

Comment: You're welcome. @MaartenSchermer That's why I always mention *"unless that's a typo"* ;-)

Comment: @Joel_Blum Yes I did consider using a php framework, however without a framework you have the freedom to code however you like and I assume you would have a large piece of unused code which is loaded on every request from the framework.

Comment: That's up to you , but unless you're a very experienced php programmer I would reconsider , it will save you a lot of bugs and time. The 'unused code' which is loaded on every request isn't really an issue for 99% of cases . Some very robust and fast websites are built with open source php frameworks.

Comment: Doctrine fully supports [autoloading](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html) which keeps runtime overhead down to a minimum. And its entity caches effectively speed up a lot of code in practice.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes , how comes that you picked the worst possible answer?

Comment: when you use code-examples here on the website, please do proper indenting of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In proper OOP, a DAL function which returns an instance of a specific class should be static within that class. As a base rule, all functionality related to one specific object should be part of that specific object, as an instance method if invoked on instances or a static method if it creates or manages instances ('factory pattern').

Your function isn't static currently, correct usage would be:

```
class Game
{
   ..other functions..

   public static function getById($id)
   {
      ..implementation, which can either access central storage or retrieve
        the object itself if concurrent edits are not an issue..
   }
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
$myGame = Game::getById(684);
```

You may want to have a look at [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html) instead of re-inventing the wheel. And even if you do want to make a new wheel, its code samples all follow correct OOP principles.

Comment: No, that's not the way to do it.

Comment: No problem. Check my answer why. "Single Responsibility Pattern"

Comment: http://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice.html Read this and re-consider. Your answer is bad.

Comment: I would tend to agree with @Anyone over this, two major flaws with this approach: lack of SRP and use of `static` (we were talking about OOP not class-based programming, no?)

Comment: @Anyone There is no such thing as Single Responsibility *Pattern* ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa indeed, it's the principle, check my post for the link, sometimes I type the wrong words ;)

Comment: I don't need to click links to know what it is ;)

Comment: Single responsibility is optional in this approach - as stated in the sample code it's up to the implementer whether `getById` calls an entity manager internally. The whole point of OOP is hiding internals from the end user, who just wants to call `Game::getById($id)`. As for why `static` functions would be wrong in OOP - a lot of design patterns disagree with you there...?

Comment: You don't need to check, but I call it a principle there

Comment: Thank you mr. Keurentjes for your fast answer and your tips ;-)! You have answered my question and therefore I will accept it. Have a nice day!

Comment: Too bad, you could have learned a lot Maarten. The fastest way isn't always the best. However Niels, you are NOT hiding the internals. What if you're making a unit-test? You're exposing your database connection because you have to initialize it to make it work.

Comment: The other way around, as stated it's entirely wrong from OOP perspective to have the coder need to think about internals like entity managers. Controller code should worry about entities, not where they're coming from, and as such the retrieval methods should be abstracted.

Comment: So you're basically saying that Doctrine2 is working incorrectly, even tho you are mentioning it in your post?

Comment: I'm using Doctrine2 in all my current projects, completely abstracted away from the end user. It doesn't prohibit or enforce any single approach, and works perfectly fine if you let it manage its entities on its own and never be exposed to the business logic code. Like a proper DAL/ORM library should, that's why we chose it as a tool of choice.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes It is also up to the user to use horrible code, we've got the choice to take the worst decisions possible. I have no idea what you meant by "a lot of design patterns disagree". Design patterns are by definition independent from the code you use.

Comment: You implied using `static` is 'wrong' in OOP. The singleton and factory patterns cannot be implemented without `static`. Hence my question mark, I have no idea what you meant with that statement.

Comment: Funny enough, both patterns are terrible. [Read here (last note of each section)](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html). Also, you are messing up definitions: design patterns have nothing to do with OOP. As to why static is bad, there's plenty of material out there, but in short the use of static causes global state which is hard to maintain and test: [1](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it) [2](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/0103_static_considered_harmful.html)

Comment: The factory pattern can be implemented as a standard object

Comment: Both that article and the one linked before about why static methods are evil in general appear to be written by shortsighted programmers who also despise `eval` and `goto` just because they **can** be abused to write terrible code. It's like refusing to use a fork and knife to eat because both can be used to murder your mother. Bad practices are up to bad programmers, not using the tools available. Anyway, we're not going to agree here, and I'm rather sick of @Anyone's personal attacks, so I'm out.

Comment: Personal attacks? o.O You feel offended rather fast if I say a method is bad :P

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes That's the wrong analogy. Here's a better one, would you use a screwdriver to eat?

Comment: @Anyone I'm open to good discussions on programming, but so far you've called me a *reputation chaser* who *gives bad answers on purpose* and should *rethink working in IT*. That's not an adult way to have a good discussion.

Comment: @Christian the analogy is exactly the same - would you say screwdrivers are bad practice and shouldn't be used just because they aren't really fit to eat with?

Comment: Yes I would if you're preferring screwdrivers over forks to eat.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes when talking about factory pattern, don't you think using static methods in the way the OP is trying (or the way you are answering) has zero to none purpose? If there's a need to create a lot of Game instances, maybe then you can implement your "static factory" that returns instances of Game depends on the params?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes indeed. "I'm just glad you're not working for me." If you can't behave like an adult, don't expect the same treatment back.

Comment: -1: recommendation of pointless framework and examples with code, that depends on global state.

Comment: I think the first sentence in your answer is incomplete. You also do not explain what the abbrevs. stand for. E.g. if there is a *layer* there should be no static, but you write it must have static. I assume this is just unprecise.

Answer (score 1):

This Answer takes another approach. Instead of getting Objects from Static Factory. This solution takes a approach of creating a blank object and then calling the database methods to make the object a live representation of a actual row.

first the observations from your question -

an Object/Instance of `Game` class represents a Row of Table `game`. And the Game class itself can be taken as a representation of `game' table.

If the above observation is correct along with the assumption that there are more tables with a representation in class hierarchy. You should have a class to represent generic 'Table'

```
class Table {   //The class itself can be made abstract depending upon the exact implementation 
   protected $_tableName;
   protected $_connectionParams;
   protected $idAttribute = 'id';

   public function __construct($tableName, $connectionParams, $idAttribute){
       $this->_connectionParams = $connectionParams;
       $this->_tableName = $tableName;
       if(isset($idAttribute)) {
          $this->idAttribute = $idAttribute;
       }
   };

   private function _getConnection() {
      //return $db using $_connectionParams
   };

   public function getByID($id) {    
      $this->getByKeyVal($this->idAttribute, $id);
   };

   public function getByKeyVal($key, $val) {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM ". $this->_tableName ." WHERE `". $key ."` = :key LIMIT 1";
      $prepare = array(":key"=> $val);
      $result = $this->_getConnection()->Precute($query,$prepare);
      $this->processRow($result[0]);
   };

   //This needs to be overridden
   public function processRow($row) {
      return true;
   };
}
```

Now extend the generic Table class for Game Table

```
class Game extends Table {
   private $_id;
   private $_name;
   private $_url;
   public function __construct($defaults) {
      if(isset($defaults) {
         if(is_array($defaults)) {
            $this->processRow($defaults);
         } else {  
            $this->getByID($defaults);
         }
      } else {
         //Some default setup here if requried
      }
      $connectionParams = [];  //Prepare Connection Params here
      parent::__construct('game', $connectionParams);
   };

   //Override processRow
   public function processRow($row) {    
      if(isset($row['id']) {
         $this->_id = $row['id'];
      }
      $this->_name = $row['name'];
      $this->_url = $row['url'];
   };
}
```

Above is a very rough example. The actual Class structure will depend upon your requirements. But the general rule of thumb is to treat a Class as a blueprint of a concrete object. And all the methods related with a Generic Classification should go in there own class.

The getConnection Method itself can be put into a seprate DB connection class and inserted in table via a either [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) pattern or generic class inheritance.

Use the above setup like this

```
$game_new = new Game();  // for blank object  --- for a new row

$game_435 = new Game(435);    //row with 435 ID

$game_default = new Game(array(    //new row with defaults
  'name' => 'Some Name',
  'url' => 'Some Url'
));
```

Comment: Please comment alongside down-vote if something is wrong with this approach.

Comment: This is a rather nice approach. I've used this before together with ActiveRecord. The only major change I'd do is replace `getById($id)` with a `getBy($key, $val)` one, since [1] sometimes you might not have an id as the PK and [2] sometimes you would want to load the item by a different criteria. Oh, and instead of `Table`, I'd make it more abstract so one can load from different places, not just DB.

Comment: Thats correct, i normally keep a protected $_idAttribute. i'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes. I tried to keep it as much close to OP's approach. The most ideal way is to define a DataReader interface. have different DataReader for database, cache, some external API, and use the DataReader as mixin. the DataReader switch can be made during the lifetime of object.

Comment: I think the 'getByKeyVal($key, $val)' function would be very usefull indeed! Although I think this is a pretty difficult approach vs the static function @Niels Keurentjes provided.

Comment: the first implementation is a bit difficult. But it becomes a real breather once you have done that. post that simply switching the database. or making a LinuxGame, WebGame from Game is super easy. You can implement various cache mechanisms as add on. Making a factory for a List (Array) of games can be done as well. and there by mixing the pattern i gave with the one from Niels.

Comment: @MaartenSchermer It's very easy actually. Instead of throwing a hardcoded string "id" everywhere, just pass on the first function parameter. It's easier, cleaner and more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a "bucket" full of Game objects. When ever you want a Game Object (representing data in your database), you ask your "bucket" to give it to you. Let me give you an example of how Doctrine2 implements this:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html

So where you want to place your "getById" (or as I would do "findById"), is in your "bucket".

```php
// lets presume that the em is an instance of \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
// The entity manager does what the name says.
$id = 1234;
$game = $entity_manager->find('MyNamespace\Entity\Game', $id);
$game->setName('My first game!');
// We now tell the em to prepare the object for pushing it back to the "bucket" or database
$entity_manager->persist($game);
// Now we tell the em to actually save stuff
$entity_manager->flush();
```

This should give you an indication of how to use it. Objects follow the **Single Responsibility Principle**. You don't ask an object to retrieve itself. You ask the "bucket" to retrieve you an Object.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: This answer is actually completely offtopic. Nice how you explain that an entity manager can eliminate overhead et al, but in the end - the call to `$entity_manager->find(...)` should be in `Game::getById`. Which is the question, not how to build an entity manager like Doctrine has.

Comment: No, because telling OP how to make a static function INSIDE the object it wrong. It solves his problem, but doesn't teach him the proper way. How do you plan on mocking your entities now? Why does your entity know about the database? How would you even serialize this? You can't serialize a connection.

Comment: The OP's question is, literally, *'where do we place the 'getByID' function'*. You're answering an awful lot of questions, except the only one the OP asked.

Comment: "where do we place the 'getByID' function?" You place it in the "bucket" aka entity manager. NOT in the entity itself.

Comment: Well, if you're going to pollute the entity manager with all sorts of crap it shouldn't know about (teaching an entity manager about every single class it's every going to contain is just about the ***WORST*** possible approach to OOP) I'm just glad you're not working for me.

Comment: You fail to understand one thing. Doctrine has an Object Manager and an Entity Manager. The latter knows about Entities and extra functionality. What it does is using Repositories (transparant, you can't see it). I'm glad I'm not working for you, because I would feel shitty going to work and being taught everything wrong. "$user = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->find($id);" If you question Doctrine2, you might want to rethink working in IT.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes actually "the worst" would be using some sort of static calls. **LIKE YOU DID IN YOUR OWN ANSWER!**

Answer (score 0):

What if I told you that there are more beautiful ways to put things on their places.
A very simple case might contain 3 basic components to work:

1. Db framework - Which handles data access.
2. Table repsotor classes - Which know how to map classes to tables,
   how to create classes from table data and how to create data from table classes.
3. Model or business layer which contain actual classes.

For better understanding imagine you have database object mapper framework.
The framework can be far complex but in few lines we can demonstrate how it`s basic
concepts work.

So the 'Framework':

```
<?php

//This class is for making link for db framework
class link
{
    public $link;
    public function __construct ($hostname, $database, $gamename, $password)
    {
        $this->link = new \PDO ('mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$database, $gamename, $password);
        $this->link->query('use '.$database);
    }
    public function fetch ($query)
    {
        $result = $this->link->query($query)->fetch();
    }
    public function query ($query)
    {
        return $this->link->query($query);
    }
    public function error ()
    {
        return $this->link->errorInfo();
    }
}

//This class collects table repositories and connections
class database
{
    public $link;
    public $tables = array ();
    public function __construct ($link)
    {
        $this->link = $link;
        table::$database = $this;
    }
}

//This is basic table repositor class
class table
{
    public static $database;
}

?>
```

Now as we have our db framework let us make some table repositor which knows
how to save/load/delete game:

```
class games extends table
{
    public function create ($row)
    {
        $return = new game ();
        $return->id = $row[0];
        $return->name = $row[1];
        var_export($row);
        return $return;
    }
    public function load ($id=null)
    {
        if ($id==null)
        {
            $result = self::$database->link->fetch("select * from games");
            if ($result)
            {
                $return = array();
                foreach ($result as $row)
                {
                    $return[$row[0]] = $this->create($row);
                }
                return $return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $result = self::$database->link->fetch("select * from games where id='".$id."'");
            if ($result)
            {
                return $this->create(reset($result));
            }
            else
            {
                echo ("no result");
            }
        }
    }
    public function save ($game)
    {
        if (is_array($save))
        {
            foreach ($save as $item) $this->save ($item);
        }
        if ($game->id==null)
        {
            return self::$database->link->query("insert into games set
                                                 name='".$game->name."'");
        }
        else
        {
            return self::$database->link->query("update games set name='".$game->name."'
                                                 where id='".$game->id."'");
        }
    }
    public function delete ($game)
    {
        self::$database->link->query ("delete from games where id='".$game->id."'");
    }
}
```

Now  we can make our model which in this case will contain actuall game class.

```
class game
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public function __construct ($name=null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

And than actually use it:

```
$database = new database (new link('127.0.0.1', 'system_db', 'root', '1234'));
$database->tables['games'] = new games();

if (!$database->tables['games']->save (new game('Admin')))
{
    var_export($database->link->error());
}

var_export($database->tables['games']->load(2));
```

For the moment I prefere this pattern for working with db in my projects. Using it I can achieve
that my actuall business objects(In this case class game) will know nothing about
where and how they are saved. This gives me an ability to be indipendent from
actuall storage and focus on project logics.

Also there is one lightweight framework so called db.php (http://dbphp.net) and it even
gives me ability to avoid to write table repositories and even creates/modifies tables
needed for my business classes on the fly but uses almost same concept I described here.

Comment: Nice one! Why not use prepared statements?